# 'numpy.ndarray' or 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'cluster_centers_'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have a dataframe **X**:

```
               A       B
        1226   11      22
    0   1227   33      44
        1228   55      66
        ...    ...     ...
        1338   12      13
   15   1338   14      15
        1339   16      17
```

A was trying to find centers of clusters:

```
clustering = AffinityPropagation().fit(X)
aa = X.loc[0]   
aa.cluster_centers_
```

And it gave me the following error:

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'cluster_centers_'
```

even after aa.values it gives me:

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'cluster_centers_'
```

[Sourse](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation.html)

Comment: How about `clustering.cluster_centers_`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call `cluster_centers_` on the first element of your dataframe, whereas you should of course call it on the `clustering` variable you define, as follows: `clustering.cluster_centers_` You can't call the `cluster_centers_` function on an element of a dataframe.

Comment: Thnaks. But there is a thing. I did the clustering based on `distance matrix`. Then I calculated elements included into this distance matrix (in my case from distance matrix a got my "taxi cars id"). So, should I calculate cluster centers also based on this matrix or I should find center of taxis(long and lat)?

Comment: Depends completely on how you want to define your clusters. Do you want to find the center of taxis, or the cluster of taxi cars id that are grouped together? By the way, please refrain from asking new questions in the comments, otherwise the posts will get really messy. Ask a new question instead if you are still stuck.

Comment: I have asked new question. But you are right, I need to understand what I want. Thanks. Should delete these comments ?

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.